# Misaligned question content

Tags: bug

The question content card is misaligned after clicking "2 new questions" in the news feed.

[image]

Comment: What is misaligned? Some [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) would be useful.